# AJAX http post encoding issues

Tags: javascript, ajax, encoding

I'm having issues with å ä ö characters in my ajax post.
This is my code:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    encoding: "UTF-8",
                    dataType: 'text',
                    url: JSurl + "/Home/UpdateCustomerData",
                    data: "jsonData=" + JSON.stringify({ customer: '@Model.name', name: names[activeService], data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend) }),
                    success: function (returnPayload) {
                        //If last component, redirect to customer view
                        if (KomponentCountTotal == KomponentCountDone) {
                            window.location.href = JSurl + '/Home/Customer?name=' + '@Model.name' + '&index=0';
                            return;
                        }


                        console && console.log("request succeeded");
                        $('#buttonDiv' + index + '').append('<div id="success" class="col-lg-12"><br /><br /><div class="alert alert-success">Sparat!</div></div>');
                        $('#success').delay(1500).fadeOut(1000, function () { $(this).remove(); });
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        console && console.log("request failed");
                        $('#buttonDiv' + index + '').append('<div id="fail" class="col-lg-12"><br /><br /><div class="alert alert-danger">Något gick fel!</div></div>');
                        $('#fail').delay(1500).fadeOut(1000, function () { $(this).remove(); });
                    },

                    processData: false,
                    async: false
                });
```

If my @Model.name is "Röd" for example, my controller recives `"{\"customer\":\"R"` as jsonData.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have set correct meta tag in html ?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: Yes, i have that set.